# I am trying to come up with a term for actions Replace/Prepend/Append

Tags: terminology, hypernyms

Let's assume I have a text in the notepad: "Some Text".

If I enter more words after the text it will be an append ("Some Text Another Text"), otherwise it will be a prepend ("Another Text Some Text"), if I don't replace the text with a new text completely ("Another Text").

So I am trying to come up with a term for these actions. How do you call it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken as a group, these are all examples of "Text Modification".

If I'm reading your comment to morganpdx correctly, you could make a title like "Text Modification Options" where you then give further information about "Appending to your text", "Prepending to your text" (or "Inserting before your text"), and "Replacing your text".

Comment: "Edit" is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 4):

The first word that comes to my mind is "Edit".

Answer (score 1):

You already have the answer.

Prepend, append and replace are all verbs.  See below, with related nouns:

Append:

> You append text after some other text.
>
> I appended some text.
>
> He will append some text.

Prepend:

> You prepend text before some other text.
>
> I prepended some text.
>
> He will prepend some text.

In either case, both of them could be called a supplement, or supplemental text.

Comment: but how do you call these verbs(or actions) if you have to explain under a title ?

Answer (score 1):

You can call it conjugation too.

[My bad, I didn't notice the word "replace." You probably need to call it a "modification" already.]

Answer (score 1):

Just another suggestion. In my experience, designers of systems often want to be systematic, which is to be expected, and want to catch similar things under a single heading. But why not describe a thing by two terms? Some Loeb translations of Plato translate many a complicated Greek word into two English words, which works rather well.

You could say **"Replace or add to text"**, or **"Replace/Add"** if you want it shorter.